# Seam and Dojo vs RichFace or IceFace 

Tags: jakarta-ee, dojo, seam, richfaces, lotus-domino

I am just scratching my head on using DoJo in Seam in place of RichFaces or IceFace. 
I couldn't find any article or tutorial out there in the web. The reason for my question is that Iam coming out of a DoJo/Domino project and like to have this project in J2EE/Seam/DoJo.

Appreciate any input...

TIA.

Comment: I want to use DoJo in Seam. I couldn't find any article or tutorial out there on the web. Appreciate any input...

Answer (score 1):

There's no reason why you can't use DOJO (or jQuery for that matter) with Seam. The only difference is that unlike Richfaces/Icefaces you aren't going to get easy "out-of-the-box" Ajax integration with your back-end Seam Beans.

But this isn't necessarily a bad thing. Consider hooking your DOJO components up to your Seam Beans using one of these methods:

- [Seam Remoting](http://docs.jboss.org/seam/2.2.0.GA/reference/en-US/html/remoting.html)
- [RESTeasy](http://docs.jboss.org/seam/2.2.0.GA/reference/en-US/html/webservices.html#d0e22078)

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand the question, what are you really asking us to tell you?

Dojo is a JavaScript framework while RichFaces and IceFaces are JSF implementations.  There are differences between RichFaces and IceFaces, without a clear idea of what the goal of your project is I don't think anyone will be able to give you a correct answer.

The requirements of the project should help you define what tools you should be using.

Comment: RichFaces and IceFaces are not JSF implementations actually, but frameworks/component libraries built over JSF.

Comment: the OP's question was't 'My project requires using Richfaces, should I use Dojo instead?'.

Answer (score 0):

Well if you asking which one is better... it's hard to say. I think if your working with Seam for the first time it would be better to stick with RichFaces as it is the default and is built to work with Seam. All of the official Seam documentation uses RichFaces also.

Answer (score 0):

Richfaces looks more good option to work than Icefaces bcoz it has inbuilt support, its easy to learn & its long time support guarantee for seam+richfaces combination.

Answer (score 0):

Seam is more powerful with JSF, but not necessarily Richfaces or Icefaces, for they mostly just extend the component set, which is anyway fall down to standard HTML components when rendered by JSF.

In my company we often use jQuery skinning + JSF standard components INSTEAD of richfaces/icefaces, because Look&Feel customization is much easier. I think with DoJo you can do something similar.

A few starting points:

[Combine JSF with Dojo widgets](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/web/library/wa-aj-jsfdojo/index.html) | [dojofaces.org](http://www.dojofaces.org) | [dojofaces creators](http://www.j4fry.org/)